# PHP boolean to string conversion unexpected

Tags: php, loops, scope

basically I set a flag that tells me if I encountered a condition inside a foreach loop:

```
            ANOTHER FOREACH IF IT CAN HELP WRAPS THIS CYCLE THRU ALL COLUMNS
            $flag = true;
            foreach ($column as $key=>$val) {
                if ($key == 0) {
                    echo 'cod: ' . $val . '---' . (string)$flag;
                }
                if ($key == 3 && $val != "" && $val != null) {
                    $flag = false;
                    echo 'Img: ' . $val  . '-------'  . (string)$flag;
                }
                //un altro array togliendo i non pubblicati
                if ($key == 8 && $val != 0 && $val != null) {
                    $flag = false;
                    echo 'pub: ' . $val  . (string)$flag;
                }
            }
            if(!$flag) {
                $datarrayo[] = $column;
            }
```

As you can see I injected an echo every check just to make sure I was in trouble, and yes I am. Both checks:

```
            if ($key == 3 && $val != "" && $val != null) {
                $flag = false;
                echo 'Img: ' . $val  . '-------'  . (string)$flag;
            }
```

1)set flag to false??

2)it prints Img "http://value.jpg" ------- 1

Yes: 1, so $flag = false does not work

Comment: first, what scope? i cant see any... well you're always in the same one.
And do i get it right that $flag is basically a boolean? And for debugging just try: 
echo 'Img: ' . $val  . '-------'  . json_encode($flag);

Comment: The only plausible reason for the `$flag` being 1 after it was set to false is that the code in your question isn't actually the code you're executing.

Comment: Dxg125, That's it, you right. I didn't expect casting (string) to a false value would give me 1! Actually flag is false, or 1 in string. Maybe I will answer myself here for anyone in trouble with printing a boolean value

Comment: Casting a boolean false to a string will never give you `1`, so the code you've posted can not possibly have generated the output indicated. I would wager that your program is actually outputting `Img: http://value.jpg-------` and then the following `1` is coming from a different echo statement that isn't shown here. (Because note, you're not outputting a new line.) Post the contents of `$column` and use `var_dump($flag);` instead of echo.

Comment: I assure you I had 1 in the exact same spot where json_encode is giving me false

Comment: We aren't denying what you see with your own eyes, but [the code in the question does not do what you say](https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5VIpS8xRsFVQyigpKbDS1wfySlP1sgrSlayBcmk5ielAybTEnOJUID81OSNfQd0zN91KQV1BTwGsFUir60KAOoijUVxSlJmXrgnWaw0A&v=8.2.4). There's a misunderstanding here, and/or code that isn't in the question.

Answer (score -3):

As user @Dxg125 pointed.
Actually $flag IS false, it's just that using its string value it's equal to 1.

So $bool = false == '1' apparently.

Just use json_encode to print a boolean value

Comment: `$flag IS false, it's just that using its string value it's equal to 1.` this is not true. False as an int is 0 and as a string is “”. As Kiko Software commented the code in the question will not do what you say, and the problem described is not reproducible. This may be helpful https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php